# How to resolve Webpack errors reacting with net core

Tags: .net, reactjs, reactjs.net

webpack problem became an error because of the typecript (ts and tsx) I changed it to javascript (js and jsx). the original code is the typescript I took from [Github](https://github.com/bradymholt/aspnet-core-react-template)

Image webpack error

[image: 1]

file webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
var releaseConfig = require("./webpack.config.release");
var isProductionEnvironment =
  process.env.ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT === "Production";
var path = require("path");
var merge = require("extendify")({ isDeep: true, arrays: "replace" });

var config = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    main: path.join(__dirname, "boot.jsx")
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "../api/", "wwwroot"),
    filename: "[name].js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".jsx", ".js", ".styl", ".css"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
              camelCase: true,
              importLoaders: 2,
              sourceMap: false,
              localIdentName: "[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
            }
          },
          {
            loader: "stylus-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
      { test: /\.css/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=100000"
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  plugins: [
    // plugins should not be empty: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices'[
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "index.ejs"),
      inject: true
    })
    // new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()
    // We do not use ExtractTextPlugin in development mode so that HMR will work with styles
  ]
};

if (isProductionEnvironment) {
  // Merge production config
  config = merge(config, releaseConfig);
}

module.exports = config;
```

and file webpack.config.relase.js

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var path = require("path");

var config = {
  mode: "production",
  module: {
    rules: [
      // Use react-hot for HMR and then ts-loader to transpile TS (pass path to tsconfig because it is not in root (cwd) path)
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use:
            "css-loader?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!stylus-loader"
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: "",
  externals: {
    react: "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      release: true,
      template: path.join(__dirname, "index.ejs"),
      useCdn: true,
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeComments: true
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
  ]
};
```

file package.json

```
{
  "name": "aspnet.core.react.template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "dotnet restore ./api && dotnet restore ./api.test",
    "build": "dotnet build ./api",
    "test:api": "cd ./api.test && dotnet test",
    "pretest:client": "npx tsc -p ./client-react.test/",
    "test:client": "mocha --require ignore-styles --recursive client-react.test/build/client-react.test",
    "test": "npm run test:api && npm run test:client",
    "migrate": "cd ./api/ && node ../scripts/create-migration.js && dotnet ef database update",
    "prestart": "docker-compose up -d",
    "start": "cd ./api && cross-env NODE_PATH=../node_modules/ ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development dotnet watch run",
    "start:release": "npm run prerelease && cd ./api/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/publish/ && dotnet api.dll",
    "provision:prod": "ansible-playbook -l production -i ./ops/config.yml ./ops/provision.yml",
    "prerelease": "cross-env ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production webpack --config ./client-react/webpack.config.js && cd ./api && dotnet publish --configuration Release",
    "deploy:prod": "npm run prerelease && ansible-playbook -l production -i ./ops/config.yml ./ops/deploy.yml",
    "ssh:prod": "ssh `grep 'deploy_user=' ./ops/hosts | tail -n1 | awk -F'=' '{ print $2}'`@`awk 'f{print;f=0} /[production]/{f=1}' ./ops/hosts | head -n 1`"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.7",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.9.1",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/jsdom": "^12.2.3",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.6",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.10",
    "@types/react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/sinon": "7.0.10",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "aspnet-webpack-react": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "dom": "^0.0.3",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.11.2",
    "extendify": "^1.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "global": "^4.3.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
    "jsdom": "^14.0.0",
    "mocha": "^6.0.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.8.0",
    "react-router": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "sinon": "7.3.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^3.3.4000",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.6.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.3",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

**how to resolve the error, I beg for your help ... because I don't know much about reactjs with .net core?**